# launchsettings.json - commandName, IIS or Project for Production?

Tags: iis, asp.net-core-mvc, kestrel-http-server, kestrel

For an MVC core live production website, I am trying to understand which `commandName` setting I should be using in my launchsettings.json. My understanding is that if I set `Project` it will use the Kestrel server to host the website. If I set `IIS` it will then use IIS.

From my research into Kestrel, it is said that Kestrel should be used behind one of the main host servers such as IIS due to its lack of features as it was scaled for performance. This begs me to wonder how I would accomplish such a thing. In my current setup, I am using shared hosting to host a website and I would like to know if I should be putting the `commandName` setting to `IIS` or `Project`, will it even make a difference in my case?

Comment: A live site on IIS should use `web.config`. `launchSettings.json` should be used only by VS during development https://blog.jetbrains.com/dotnet/2018/11/08/using-net-core-launchsettings-json-rundebug-apps-rider/

Comment: @LexLi I'm not sure I follow what you are trying to say with that.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/iis/?view=aspnetcore-2.2  No step requires that file. The JetBrains post clearly says what is stored in the JSON file and is only for development usage (consumed by an IDE, Rider or VS).

Comment: @LexLi so you are saying when I publish this to production (in Release Mode) this file is completely ignored and IIS is always used for the hosting?

Comment: @LexLi - If launchsetting json is meant only for dev purposes, then why does the documentation here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/linux-apache?view=aspnetcore-6.0#publish-and-copy-over-the-app ask us to modify the `launchSettings.json`?

Comment: @variable When I posted that comment in 2019, the article didn't contain anything like that. I don't know why Microsoft adds "Remove https://localhost:5001 (if present) from the applicationUrl property in the Properties/launchSettings.json file" either. You can read more from https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/environments?view=aspnetcore-6.0#development-and-launchsettingsjson